# Alernative command in CentOS

Tags: linux, shell, grep

Following command is **working** on **Ubuntu**

```
iv2user@ubuntu-serverA1:~$ ps ax | grep -v grep | grep -v $0 | grep script_master_01.py
20656 pts/2    S+     0:00 python script_master_01.py
```

where I am running py file, as `python script_master_01.py`

But command **not working** on **CentOS 6.5**

```
[iv2user@dev3 ~]$ ps ax | grep -v grep | grep -v $0 | grep cqc_script_master_76.py
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.
```

**Can you help me because I do not respective command for CentOS.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In variable $0 you have different values, in ubuntu just "bash", in centOS "-bash", so with dash it thinks, that there must be some options

Comment: The solution (not mentioned in the answer for some reason) is to replace `$0` with `-e $0`.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try the below as it will weed out other results you do not want:

```
ps ax | grep cqc_script_master_76.p[y]
```

Comment: Quick Question I'm new to stack overflow...why did you edit my response?